# push the stack value in list view

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I have a value in texblocknumber.text="123".when I press the button every time, I want to push the value in stack ,and then show the stack value in list view.
I have two error in the above code
1. I want to add a texblocknumber.text in a stack.Push(texblocknumber.text); 
2. I want to add a stack .push value in list view

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="mylist1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="texblocknumber"  Text="{Binding datetime}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txt2"   Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

c# code

```
    static Stack<string> GetStack()
    {

        Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();

        stack.Push("fghj");
        stack.Push("bnmc");
        return stack;
    }
```

Comment: i thought you are are new to binding work..ok just wait i will come up with en example ..

Comment: have you check the code i have put ?

Comment: dude what happen is it not working for you..atleast reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the binding for the button and use **Observable collection** as source for your list instead of stack as it implements **INotifycollectionchanged**.

Answer (score 0):

```
just check this solution what i am doing in it on btn click i am saving content on a observablecollection..and simulataneously i have binded it to listbox..(i am showing with collection of string..you can do it with collection of objects too)..
```

you listbox ..

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOFText}" x:Name="mylist1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="texblocknumber"  Text="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt2"   Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

your page.cs ..

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOFText { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListOFText = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.DataContext = this;


    }

    private void Mubutton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Button btnObj = sender as Button;
        ListOFText.Add(btnObj.Content.ToString());

    }


}
```

hope this helps you..any query..comment below..